# How do I run MySQL commands?

Tags: mysql, command-line, phpmyadmin, dreamhost, symphony-cms

I'm in the process of updating my Symphony installation and I've been told to "run these MySQL commands" to complete the process. Funny thing... I have no idea how to do that. The commands I'm mean to run are as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE  `sym_sections` ADD  `navigation_group` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  'Content';
ALTER TABLE  `sym_sections` ADD INDEX (  `navigation_group` ) ;
ALTER TABLE `tbl_entries_data_XX` CHANGE `mimetype` `mimetype` VARCHAR( 50 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

I'm using Coda on the Mac (if that helps) and I have access to PHPMyAdmin on my host server. My host is Dreamhost.

Feel free to talk down to me, I have absolutely no idea about this sort of stuff, I'm a UI designer, not a back-end developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use PHPmyAdmin
2. select your Database
3. Select the SQL-TAB
4. Paste the Code in the TextBox in PHPmySQL :
   [alt text http://www.holo-dek.com/guild/stats/docs/img/phpmyadmin_sql_de.gif](http://www.holo-dek.com/guild/stats/docs/img/phpmyadmin_sql_de.gif)

Answer (score 1):

Open PHPMyAdmin, in the panel on the left use the drop down box to select your database.

Then in the database view on the right, select the "SQL" tab, and copy/paste the SQL code in and click the "Go" button.